# Transfer selected mysql table data from one server DB to other server DB using php native code

Tags: php, mysql

I have to transfer selected mysql data one server  DB to other Server DB but issue is that i only have to use native php code

I can  do it  using  `shell_exec or exec` command in php  but i am not allowed to use any linux shell command.

I have to fetch selected data from the table then do the sql dump and data count is also huge so i don't know it is possible with php native code or not because it may get session out because of large amount of data.

**what i have tried**
https://github.com/2createStudio/shuttle-export

it support php based sql dump but i need selected data from table with conditions like

`select * from customer where table_id=47`

I have check few more example but not finding anything concrete

Please suggest how i can proceed.

Thanks